# Como rodar em desenvolvimento o servidor puma com SSL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrtc

Minha aplicação em Rails 5 utiliza WebRTC, e o WebRTC (câmera, etc) só funciona com SSL habilitado. Utilizo servidor puma localmente.

Quais os procedimento corretos para efetivar e habilitar o suporte SSL no servidor puma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por padrão o Rails não oferece esse recurso, é necessário ser configurado, gerar certificados SSL. Abaixo detalho o procedimento.

## Self-Signed SSL Certificate

Vamos gerar os certificados auto-assinados, irei colocar na aplicação para que outros da equipe se beneficiem desta configuração. Crie um diretório `certificates` dentro da pasta `config` em sua aplicação e rode os comandos abaixo:

```
cd config/certificates

openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.orig.key 2048
openssl rsa -in server.orig.key -out server.key
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

> Estas instruções foram tiradas [deste gist](https://gist.github.com/tadast/9932075).

## Puma

Abra o arquivo `puma.rb` e adicione ao final a diretiva `bind` com suas respectivas configurações:

```
ssl_key = File.expand_path('../certificates/server.key', __FILE__)
ssl_cert = File.expand_path('../certificates/server.crt', __FILE__)
bind "ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?key=#{ssl_key}&cert=#{ssl_cert}"
```

Lembre-se de forçar a conexão SSL no Rails. Abra o arquivo `development.rb` e adicione `config.force_ssl = true`.

Infelizmente através do comando `rails server` não será possível iniciar o servidor com SSL, isso acontece pois o `rails server` não lê as configurações do arquivo `puma.rb`. [De uma olhada nesta questão](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24435) para entender melhor o problema. Para iniciar o servidor utilize o comando `puma`.

Feito isso seu servidor irá rodar utilizando SSL.

## Logger

Rodando o servidor através do comando `puma` não irá trazer os logs da aplicação. Para resolver isso, abra o arquivo `development.rb` e adicione as instruções abaixo:

```
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
```

Comment: parabéns, estou no caminho, mas teria o tutorial completo para habilitar o https em minha rails api? obrigado Bruno!

Comment: Não tenho, faz alguns anos que não atuo com rails.